# I am getting an [expected unqualified-id] error on the second to last curly bracket

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
//This program will calculate the area of a circle and the volume of the sphere using a given 
radius value//
using namespace std;


void multivalues(int & , int & , int &, int&) ;

int main()
{
   int value, squared, cubed, fourth;
   value = 2;

   multivalues(value,squared,cubed,fourth);

  cout << "The value of the squared is " << squared << endl;
  cout << "The value of the cubed is " << cubed << endl;
  cout << "The value of the fourth is " << fourth << endl;

  return 0;
} 

void multivalues(int  &val, int  &sq, int  &cb, int  &fth);
{
  sq = pow(val, 2);
  cb = pow(val, 3);
  fth = pow(val, 4);
}
```

This is for an assignment leading to understanding passing by reference. This program should calculate the area of a circle and the volume of the sphere using a given value. It doesn't compile however.

Comment: "_basic ass question_" ? Please ... You'll have to write until people understand your problem and you've provided a [mre] - which you now have which is why Joseph managed to point out the error for you.

Comment: The less code you have, the less explanation  is required. Next time try to isolate the bug. If you had you would have either spotted the mistake yourself or had a program that was about 6 lines long, and mostly whitespace and brackets. When you have a problem and you don't know what or where it is, the first step is to divide and conquer: start removing everything that isn't part of the bug.

Comment: Side note: `pow` on `int`s can have unfortunate side effects. `pow` operates on floating point numbers and the results are typically close-enough rather than exact. `pow(5,2)` can result in 24.9999999999 rather than 25, and when you stuff 24.9999999 into an `int`, the fraction part is dropped leaving you with a noticeably wrong 24.

Answer (score 4):

You have a `;` where you don't want one:

```
void multivalues(int  &val, int  &sq, int  &cb, int  &fth);
{
  sq = pow(val, 2);
  cb = pow(val, 3);
  fth = pow(val, 4);
}
```

Look at the end of the first line I included.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. Larson